# Is $x = 2^6$ a statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm reading Susanna Epp's book on discrete mathematics.

The exercise 2.1.5 ask which sentences are statements, a statement being something that is either true or false but not both.

Question: is $x=2^6$ a statement?
Can equations with variables be statements?

Comment: Can you determine if $x=2^6$ is true?

Comment: To answer your second question: $$(x + y)^{2} = x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}$$ is a true statement for real variables $x,y$.

Comment: No because we cannot determine its truth value

Comment: @ErikEriksson That's right. As it stands, the "claim" $x=2^6$ is not a statement because there's no way to rule it as "true" or "false".

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813) is an answer to a similar question.