# How should $\exists x P(x)\land\exists y Q(y)$ be interpreted?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

If I encounter an statement like the following:
$$\exists x P(x)\land\exists y Q(y)$$

Should this be interpreted as if x and y refer necessarily to different objects or it is to be interpreted as they may or may not be the same object?

Is it therefore equivalent to:
$$\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)$$   ?

Comment: It is equivalent. There are no further conditions on satisfying objects so being equal is allowed.

Comment: $\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)$ is not the same as $\exists x P(x)\land Q(x)$. In the last instance, it has to be the same $x$. I prefer using two different letters ($x$ and $y$) to stress the difference, especially for persons starting in logic.

Comment: The variable $x$ is a *bound* variable, and its "scope" is the part of the sentence surrounded by the existential quantifier - it does not "exist" outside. The same for $y$. In other words, even if you write $(\exists x)P(x)\land (\exists x)Q(x)$, the "$x$" in the first part is *different* from the "$x$" in the second part. Thus, why not remove ambiguity, use different letters for different things, and write $(\exists x)P(x)\land (\exists y)Q(y)$ ? Both are correct but the latter is clearer.

Comment: Both versions say "P is non-empty and Q is non-empty."

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank You! So, just to be clear, in this kind of statements the scope of the first existential quantifier finishes at the $\land$ symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> just to be clear, in this kind of statements, the scope of the first existential quantifier finishes at the $∧$ symbol?

Yes, the convention is that *quantifiers apply to as little as construeable*; so, parentheses are required when the quantification is meant to apply beyond this. For example, \begin{align}\big(\forall x\, A(x)\big)\to B(x)\quad\equiv\quad\forall x \, A(x)\to B(x)\quad\not\equiv\quad\forall x\;\big(A(x)\to B(x)\big).\end{align}

(For unambiguity and good practice, the first, second, fourth, and fifth occurrences of $x$ in the above ought to be replaced with $y.$)

> Is $$\exists x P(x)\land\exists y Q(y)\tag1$$ equivalent to $$\exists x P(x)\land\exists x Q(x)\;?\tag2$$

Yes, sentences $(1)$ and $(2)$ are logically equivalent to each other.

> Should this be interpreted as if $x$ and $y$ refer necessarily to
> different objects, or it is to be interpreted as they may or may not
> be the same object?

The latter. For example, if predicates $P$ and $Q$ symbolise “is Taiwanese” and “likes to read”, respectively, and Brigitte is a Taiwanese bookworm, then both variables $x$ and $y$ in sentence $(1)$ *can* refer to her.

Comment: Thank you! So, $\forall x \, A(x)\to B(x)$ should be written as $\forall y \, A(y)\to B(x)$ and be interpreted as: whenever every element y makes A(y) true then another element x makes B(x) true?

Comment: @Martx 1. $∀yA(y)→B(x)$ is [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813) actually a sentence, due to the variable $x$ hanging free. 2. On the other hand, $∃x\Big(∀yA(y)→B(x)\Big)$ and $∀yA(y)→∃xB(x)$ (they are equivalent sentences) are understood as "whenever every $y$ makes $A(y)$ true, some $x$ makes $B(x)$ true". Notice that, unlike your translation, mine avoids saying "another $x$" or "some other $x$"? This is because, as my Brigitte example illustrates, both variables $x$ and $y$ ***can*** still point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent statements in theory . because $
x$ and $y$ concern only the statement they are in *(they are called bound variables as mentioned in the comments)*.

**So in theory** you can name both of them $
x$

However in practice , you should note them  differently, it is necessary to do so actually  .

Otherwise during the reasoning for example you can't differentiate the $
x$ that satisfies $
P$ from the one that satisfies $
Q$ which will lead to an unnecessary ambiguity .

Comment: I don't think this is right. The question is tagged "logic" so presumably is about the topic "logic" as a branch of mathematics. So given a formula $\phi$ it may very well use $x$ at varies places tied to different quantifiers. If we replace some of these with other symbols and get a formula $\hat{\phi}$ then this is not equal to $\phi$. Depending on what we are doing we will have to check out that if we can prove one we can prove the other etc etc; or that structures which model one model the other etc etc. So without knowing the OP's precise logic we don't know if we can juggle the letters.