# Can conditional statements have unquantified variables in the hypothesis or conclusion?

Tags: propositional-calculus

How do quantified/unquantified variables work when considering conditional statements? The conditional **is** a statement, but the variables in the individual *hypothesis*/*conclusion* don't have to be quantified? i.e., can the *hypothesis*/*conclusion* be predicates and not have to be statements?

For example, "If $x$ is a real number, then $x^2 \geq 0$" is a conditional statement, hypothesis = "$x$ is a real number", conclusion = "$x^2 \geq 0$". The conclusion here is a predicate, not a statement (since $x$ is not quantified). (Or is there some implicit universal set based on the hypothesis?)

Also, in the contrapositive "If $x^2 < 0$, then $x$ is not a real number," now is $x$ not quantified in both the hypothesis and the conclusion?

Comment: I addressed your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813); the short of it is that informally, $P(x){\implies}Q(x)$ is shorthand for $\forall x\,\big(P(x){\implies}Q(x)\big).\quad$ However do note that $\forall x\,P(x){\implies}\forall x\,Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x\,\forall y\,\big(P(x){\implies}Q(y)\big)$  instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit "for all" in statements of that form. We'd formalize "if $x$ is a real number, then $x^2\ge0$" as $\forall x(x\in\Bbb R\implies x^2\ge0)$. This way every well-formed statement has no free (i.e. unquantified) variables.

I'd say that the hypothesis and conclusion appear "in a quantified context" in which $x$ is bound, so in this context they represent statements and not predicates.

Notice that the variable names matter: $P(x,y)\implies Q(x,y)$ is very different from $P(x,y)\implies Q(y,x)$. Thinking of the conditional as operating on predicates doesn't make sense unless we associate extra "variable coordination information" with the operation.

Comment: I think this confirms that indeed the hypothesis and conclusion, standing each on their own, are predicates and not statements. We get a statement only after the two predicates are combined in the conditional and the quantifier is applied to the conditional.

Comment: I think you could say they're open formulas but not predicates, since variable name coordination matters. I edited my answer to elaborate on this.