# Are opinions considered propositions?

Tags: logic, logic-translation

I was wondering the thought. My textbook says:

> A proposition is still a proposition whether its truth value is known to be true, known to be false, unknown, or a matter of opinion.
>
> 1. "It is a nice day" - This is not a proposition
> 2. "All Politicians are dishonest" - This is a proposition
> 3. "The movie was funny" -This is a proposition.

Then wouldn't statement 1 be considered a proposition, especially since it says that being a matter of opinion doesn't change the fact is a proposition? Or maybe this doesn't matter at all?

Comment: This is more suited for philosophy stack exchange. To give you a cursory answer however, a proposition is a truth-bearer- an object that is capable of having a truth value.

Comment: What textbook is it?

Comment: I personally don't know if I agree if a statement can still be a proposition in a mathematical sense if the truth value is a matter of opinion. But I'm sure someone on here knows more than I do about this.

Comment: i would throw this book into the garbage.

Comment: in particular, you are right that if you adopt the (quite useless) definition of proposition given in the book, the number 1 must be a proposition as much as 3 is.

Answer (score 1):

Let's adopt a predicate-logic perspective.

> > A proposition is still a proposition whether its truth value is known to be true, known to be false, unknown, or a matter of opinion."

I think your textbook is trying to say that a proposition's truth value is allowed to vary across contexts/interpretations. In this sense, the truth value of the proposition “Jan 1 2020 was a nice day” varies according to the particular location and the definition of “nice day”, as supplied by the context. (This is my best guess as to why it admits a subjective claim as a proposition.)

To be clear: in the above, your textbook is not *defining* a proposition, nor suggesting that $(x=x)$ is a proposition (despite even having a definite truth value, it technically isn't a proposition; see below).

> > 1. "It is a nice day" - This is not a proposition
> > 2. "All Politicians are dishonest" - This is a proposition
> > 3. "The movie was funny" -This is a proposition.

I think your textbook is translating the above natural-language sentences as

1. $N(x)$
2. $\forall x\;[P(x)\to\lnot H(x)]$
3. $F(c).$

$c$ is a constant; $x$ is a free variable, so (1) is an [open formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813), so it is not a proposition (which conventionally means a formula with no free variable).

Summing up: I think your textbook is letting context/interpretation deal with subjectivity, so is not using the latter as a criteria in evaluating whether the three examples are sentences. That "matter of opinion" point above was an unhelpful (complicating) detour; actually, even the typical “A proposition is either true or false but not both” characterisation isn't very clear, because the proposition “for each $x,\;x^2$ is not a negative number” ***is*** a proposition, is true in real analysis but false in complex analysis, and has a definite truth value only under a *particular* interpretation.

Comment: The day might be "nice" to one person but not "nice" to another person.  "It is a nice day" is NOT either true or false to all.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey What's with the caps lock? And your comment is entirely consistent with my Answer.

Comment: “it is a nice day” has “it”, which in the standard meaning as it’s used in natural language has the same usage as “the” in “the movie was funny”, i.e. it is of type $N(c)$ where c = the present day.

Comment: @lola Yes, for sure. Nonetheless, this Answer is an attempt in (helping the OP make sense of their textbook by) making excuses for the textbook, and I'm imagining the author robotically translate "It is a nice day" as "$x$ is a nice day." (I mean, conceivably, the elements of the domain might be Christmas Day, Black Friday, etc.) But yes, quite contrived.

Comment: i understood that you were just attempting at making excuses for the book. i wanted to remark that the book’s example is quite debatable and that the best thing would be to find another book.

Comment: @lola Yes, I'd totally switch texts too.