# Is something like $x=x$ a proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I learned in discrete math class that a sentence like $x+2=4$ is not a proposition, because the truth value depends on the value of $x$. It is a propositional function. However, my question is, are propositional functions which are always true or always false, themselves propositions? So, would $x=x$ and also $x \neq x$ be propositions? Note, I am not talking about quantifiers, I mean just $x=x$ by itself, not $(\forall x) x =x $.

Comment: $\forall x(x=x)$ is a proposition, as is $\exists x(x=x)$; with $x$ a dummy variable, $x=x$ is a _[unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_function) [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))_, as is something less trivial such as $x+2=4$.

Comment: $x+2=4 \iff x \in \{2\}$.  Similarly $x=x \iff x \in \Omega$ and $x \not=x  \iff  x \in \emptyset$.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813), I explained that while $x=x$ is logically valid, it is technically nevertheless an open formula (propositional function) rather than a sentence/proposition.